# pythonic way to aggregate arrays (numpy or not)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, aggregate

I would like to make a nice function to aggregate data among an array (it's a numpy record array, but it does not change anything)

you have an array of data that you want to aggregate among one axis: for example an array of `dtype=[(name, (np.str_,8), (job, (np.str_,8), (income, np.uint32)]` and you want to have the mean income per job

I did this function, and in the example it should be called as `aggregate(data,'job','income',mean)`

---

```
def aggregate(data, key, value, func):

    data_per_key = {}

    for k,v in zip(data[key], data[value]):

        if k not in data_per_key.keys():

            data_per_key[k]=[]

        data_per_key[k].append(v)

    return [(k,func(data_per_key[k])) for k in data_per_key.keys()]
```

---

the problem is that I find it not very nice I would like to have it in one line: do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your answer Louis

PS: I would like to keep the func in the call so that you can also ask for median, minimum...

Comment: I don't know numpy, but your `dtype` does seem to have a problem with the brackets..

Comment: The parenthesis don't match.  Makes for some extra confusion.

Comment: I don't understand your comment that you "would like to have it in one line".  When you call the function, that will be one line.  Does it matter how many lines the function itself has?  Anyway, I think your best bet is to use `defaultdict` as the answers say.

Comment: soory for the mismatch, I changed the names and types to be explicit and forgot some brackets...
in 1 line as in the matplotlib.mlab answer

Comment: [Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/users/715042/michael) and I have created a package called [`numpy-groupies`](https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies), which includes a function for this.  The package is on pypi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the function you are seeking is [matplotlib.mlab.rec_groupby](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.rec_groupby):

```
import matplotlib.mlab

data=np.array(
    [('Aaron','Digger',1),
     ('Bill','Planter',2),
     ('Carl','Waterer',3),
     ('Darlene','Planter',3),
     ('Earl','Digger',7)],
    dtype=[('name', np.str_,8), ('job', np.str_,8), ('income', np.uint32)])

result=matplotlib.mlab.rec_groupby(data, ('job',), (('income',np.mean,'avg_income'),))
```

yields

```
('Digger', 4.0)
('Planter', 2.5)
('Waterer', 3.0)
```

`matplotlib.mlab.rec_groupby` returns a recarray:

```
print(result.dtype)
# [('job', '|S7'), ('avg_income', '<f8')]
```

---

You may also be interested in checking out [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/), which has even [more versatile facilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762454/calculate-within-categories-equivalent-of-rs-ddply-in-python/7767695#7767695) for handling [group-by operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html).

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for: the job done in one line! Moreover it's returning directly an array! Perfect!

Answer (score 5):

Your `if k not in data_per_key.keys()` could be rewritten as `if k not in data_per_key`, but you can do even better with [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects). Here's a version that uses `defaultdict` to get rid of the existence check:

```
import collections

def aggregate(data, key, value, func):
    data_per_key = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in zip(data[key], data[value]):
        data_per_key[k].append(v)

    return [(k,func(data_per_key[k])) for k in data_per_key.keys()]
```

Comment: I'd change the last line to `return [(k,f(v)) for k,v in data_per_key.items()]`

Comment: That's a good call, but I was trying to highlight the `defaultdict` stuff by making that the only change. Your return is definitely better, though.

Comment: thanks for the defaultdict trick! and also for the final iteration

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2022:**

There is a package which emulates the functionality of matlabs accumarray quite well. You can install it via `pip install numpy_groupies` or find it here:

https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies

Answer (score 2):

Best flexibility and readability is get using [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/):

```
import pandas

data=np.array(
    [('Aaron','Digger',1),
     ('Bill','Planter',2),
     ('Carl','Waterer',3),
     ('Darlene','Planter',3),
     ('Earl','Digger',7)],
    dtype=[('name', np.str_,8), ('job', np.str_,8), ('income', np.uint32)])

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
result = df.groupby('job').mean()
```

Yields to :

```
         income
job
Digger      4.0
Planter     2.5
Waterer     3.0
```

Pandas DataFrame is a great class to work with, but you can get back your results as you need:

```
result.to_records()
result.to_dict()
result.to_csv()
```

And so on...

Comment: `pandas` is about an order of magnitude slower than my solution given above. See the speed comparison there.

Comment: @Michael, sorry, actually I didn't mean performance, I'm aware that pandas is not a library aiming top performance, I myself prefer using approaches like bincount for performance. I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Best performance is achieved using [ndimage.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.mean.html#scipy.ndimage.mean) from [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/). This will be twice faster than accepted answer for this small dataset, and about 3.5 times faster for larger inputs:

```
from scipy import ndimage

data=np.array(
    [('Aaron','Digger',1),
     ('Bill','Planter',2),
     ('Carl','Waterer',3),
     ('Darlene','Planter',3),
     ('Earl','Digger',7)],
    dtype=[('name', np.str_,8), ('job', np.str_,8), ('income', np.uint32)])

unique = np.unique(data['job'])
result=np.dstack([unique, ndimage.mean(data['income'], data['job'], unique)])
```

Will yield to:

```
array([[['Digger', '4.0'],
        ['Planter', '2.5'],
        ['Waterer', '3.0']]],
      dtype='|S32')
```

## EDIT: with bincount (faster!)

This is about 5x faster than accepted answer for the small example input, if you repeat the data 100000 times it will be around 8.5x faster:

```
unique, uniqueInd, uniqueCount = np.unique(data['job'], return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
means = np.bincount(uniqueInd, data['income'])/uniqueCount
return np.dstack([unique, means])
```

Answer (score 0):

http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#dictionary-get-method

should help to make it a little prettier, more pythonic, more efficient possibly.  I'll come back later to check on your progress.  Maybe you can edit the function with this in mind?  Also see the next couple of sections.