# Calculate within categories: Equivalent of R's ddply in Python?

Tags: python, r

I have some R code I need to port to python. However, R's magic data.frame and ddply are keeping me from finding a good way to do this in python.

Sample data (R):

```
x <- data.frame(d=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),c=c(rep(c('a','b','c'),2)),v=1:6)
```

Sample computation:

```
y <- ddply(x, 'd', transform, v2=(v-min(v))/(max(v)-min(v)))
```

Sample output:

```
  d c v  v2
1 1 a 1 0.0
2 1 b 2 0.5
3 1 c 3 1.0
4 2 a 4 0.0
5 2 b 5 0.5
6 2 c 6 1.0
```

So here's my question for the pythonistas out there: how would you do the same? You have a data structure with a couple of important dimensions.

For each (c), and each(d) compute (v-min(v))/(max(v)-min(v))) and associate it with the corresponding (d,c) pair.

Feel free to use whatever data structures you want, so long as they're quick on reasonably large datasets (those that fit in memory).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Indeed [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net) is the right (and only, I believe) tool for this in Python. It's a bit less magical than plyr but here's how to do this using the groupby functionality:

```
df = DataFrame({'d' : [1.,1.,1.,2.,2.,2.],
                'c' : np.tile(['a','b','c'], 2),
                'v' : np.arange(1., 7.)})
# in IPython
In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
   c  d  v
0  a  1  1
1  b  1  2
2  c  1  3
3  a  2  4
4  b  2  5
5  c  2  6
```

Now write a small transform function:

```
def f(group):
    v = group['v']
    group['v2'] = (v - v.min()) / (v.max() - v.min())
    return group
```

Note that this also handles NAs since the `v` variable is a pandas `Series` object.

Now group by the `d` column and apply f:

```
In [36]: df.groupby('d').apply(f)
Out[36]: 
   c  d  v  v2 
0  a  1  1  0  
1  b  1  2  0.5
2  c  1  3  1  
3  a  2  4  0  
4  b  2  5  0.5
5  c  2  6  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough example.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/) and [group by or aggregate](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=125).

Comment: And a further guess: the "transform groups" method about 1/4 down the page of that second link.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve more performance if you use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/).

Despite some ugly code it will be faster, pandas way will be slow if number of groups is very large and may even be worse than R. This will always be faster than R:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions
from scipy import ndimage

x = np.rec.fromarrays(([1,1,1,2,2,2],['a','b','c']*2,range(1, 7)), names='d,c,v')

unique, groups = np.unique(x['d'], False, True)
uniques = range(unique.size)
mins = ndimage.minimum(x['v'], groups, uniques)[groups]
maxs = ndimage.maximum(x['v'], groups, uniques)[groups]

x2 = np.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(x, 'v2', (x['v'] - mins)/(maxs - mins + 0.0))

#save as csv
np.savetxt('file.csv', x2, delimiter=';')
```